# Modify lines in a file which meet two conditions with sed or awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am trying to remove the last 5 characters of lines in a file which meet two specific criteria. The line must begin with the letter E and the second column of data must equal the number 2. 
Example shown below:

Raw:

```
E1234B123 1 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 3 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 4 4 12345A 12345 123.4
C1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345 123.4
```

Should end up being:

```
E1234B123 1 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345
E1234B123 3 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 4 4 12345A 12345 123.4
C1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345 123.4
```

I believe this can be done with both awk and sed, but I don't quite have a grasp using them yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/^E/ && $2=="2" {$0=substr($0,1,length($0)-5)}1' file
E1234B123 1 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345
E1234B123 3 4 12345A 12345 123.4
E1234B123 4 4 12345A 12345 123.4
C1234B123 2 4 12345A 12345 123.4
```

It search for a line starting with `E` and second field equal `2`, then remove last 5 characters.

---

Removing last column:

```
awk '/^E/ && $2=="2" {NF--}1' file
```

---

Replace last 5 characters with space:

```
awk '/^E/ && $2=="2" {$0=substr($0,1,length($0)-5)"     "}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne, this works and is easier for me to understand. However, I've just found out that I can't just simply remove the characters, I need to replace them with blank spaces. Is this still something awk can do or would it be better to utilize sed?

Comment: See updated post on how to replace last 5 characters with space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk '{if ((substr($1,0,1)~"E") && (substr($2,0,1)~"2")) for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++) printf("%s ", $i)} END {  printf("\n")}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ "^E" && $2 =="2") $(NF--)="";print}' data
```

this removes the last column, not the 5 characters

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ "^E" && $2 =="2") print substr($0,0,length($0)-5); else print}' data
```

this removes 5 characters.

or in perl:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^E.*\s2\s.*/){ print substr($_,0,-6)."\n" } else {print}' data
```

Comment: This could be shorten, see my post.